# Flutter color half container in a triangle shape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I want to half color the container green like this

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing,You can use `LinearGradient` .

```dart
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      stops: [.5, .5],
      begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      end: Alignment.topRight,
      colors: [
        Colors.green,
        Colors.transparent, // top Right part
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Decorate the way you want. More about [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)